# 'Property of value undefined' - how to fix undefined props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass an array with numbers to a method that should list the numbers on my localhost 'website'. 
But for some reason the browser prompts that the property 'props.value' is undefined, even though I pass the value in the NumberList function.

I can manage to get it to work, if I get rid of ItemList function, and instead creates the

code in the NumberList function, but I want to split the function into two functions.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function ListItem({props}) {
return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList({numbers}) {
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <ListItem key={number.toString()} 
            value={number} />
);
return (
    <ul>
        {listItems}
    </ul>
);
}

// function NumberList({ numbers }) {
//     const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
//         <li key={number.toString()}
//         > {number}</li>
//     );
//     return listItems;
// }


function NumberTable({ numbers }) {
const tableItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <table key={number.toString()}>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{number}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
return tableItems;
}

function ListDemo(props) {
return (
    <div>
        <h2>All numbers passed in via props</h2>
        <NumberList numbers={props.numbers} />
    </div>
);
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
state = { numbers: [1, 2, 3] }
render() {
    return <ListDemo numbers={this.state.numbers} />;
}
}
```

Expected result: listed numbers on the localhost webpage
Actual result: 'Property 'props.value' is undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're destructing the props in `function ListItem({props}) {` which means that props will actually have the value of whatever `props.props` is (undefined). Either put value instead of props or don't destruct it.

Comment: Thank you so much! (I'm new to react)... :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using destructuring in the parameters of your `ListItem` function: `{props}` use just `props` instead.